# Principled Shader Material Stretching

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am trying to apply a principled bsdf material to an object. When I made the object in 1m x 1m, the material looks great. After stretching the object and apply its scale to 10m x 1m, the material becomes stretched.

1m x 1m:

[[image: 1m x 1m:1]

10m x 1m:

[image: 10m x 1m]

Node setup:

[image: Node setup:]

Notes:

- Scale has been applied
- There are no image texture

Comment: Use *"texture coordinates"* node with object or generated as input for the noise texture. Probably you've a UV map that is use by default here.

Comment: @JachymMichal, yes you are right, of course. Object coordinates...

Comment: @JachymMichal, it's not a bug, it's a feature ;) According to the doc : "Range from 0.0 to 1.0 over the bounding box of the undeformed mesh"

Comment: @thibsert Oh thanks, guess I never got to reading that part carefully :).

Answer (score 1):

If not supplied a *Texture Coordinate* node, Blender's procedural textures default to using *Generated* coordinates. These put X,Y,Z = 0 at the minimum XYZ of an object's bounding box, and X,Y,Z = 1 at the  maximums. So if the object's dimensions are not equal (scaled or not), the texture will be stretched.

You can transform the *Generated* texture space in the object's *Data* tab *> Texture Space* panel, but it's more common to add a *Texture Coordinate* node, and  explicitly put the texture into the *Object*'s own space, which is measured from 0 at the object's origin, in Blender units along the object's local axes, before any object-level transformation.

If the texture is in the Object space, then it will rotate, translate, and scale with the object. (Then, if you scale in Object mode, the texture will stretch. If you scale the object's *mesh*, in Edit mode, or bake the object's scale transform into its mesh by *Apply*ing the scale, it will not.)